# Split a DataFrame vertically based on delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

Say I have this DataFrame:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(['eggs, spam', 'lobster', 'eggs, lobster'], columns=['ingredients'])
>>> df
     ingredients
0     eggs, spam
1        lobster
2  eggs, lobster
```

I would like to split the column 'ingredients' based on the delimiter ', '. I would like to end up with a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
     ingredients
0     eggs
1     spam
2     lobster
3     eggs
4     lobster
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using **`split`** and **`stack`**

```
df.ingredients.str.split(', ', expand=True).stack().reset_index(drop=True)

0       eggs
1       spam
2    lobster
3       eggs
4    lobster
dtype: object
```